# How do I use java streams to avoid mutation on this code?

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that is functioning the way I need it to. But I was curious if it can be written better using java streams to avoid mutability.

```
public void method(List<Map<String, String>> list)
{
  List<Map<String, Object>> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map<String, String> entry : list)
    {
        // assume replaceValues(entry) does some logic and returns an updated map
        Map<String, Object> updatedMap = replaceValues(entry);
        expectedList.add(updatedMap);
    }
}
```

How can I use java streams here?

Comment: `List<Map<String, Object>> expectedList = list.stream().map(Whatever::replaceValues).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @LouisWasserman pls put that as an answer. (this::replaceValues will probably do)

Comment: *"to avoid mutability"* What "mutability" do you believe the use of streams will avoid, and why do you believe that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.stream().map(this::replaceValues).collect(Collectors.toList());

This is small refactoring, but what do you mean "avoid mutations"?

Comment: what I meant by avoiding mutability is to output the list of maps only once instead of constantly adding more maps to it inside a for loop

Comment: @RonApple1996 I think that example will cover your requirements.

Comment: Please request clarifications such as "what do you mean by..." by commenting on the OP's question.